# Blazor Server, как получить тело запроса?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Допустим, что есть страница Login.
Есть модель: LoginModel.
Когда нажимаю на кнопку "Войти", то как получить сырые данные (json)?
Через IHttpContextAccessor в Body ничего нет.
По идее SignalR должен всё перегонять в JSON. В Middleware тоже ничего нет.
Как можно это побороть? Или переезжать только ради этого на огромный WASM, чтобы дергать свои же контроллеры?